# Problem updating with library Pytorchvideo

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to run the code of this repo: https://github.com/eladb3/ORViT/. Is using slowfast model.

There's one part of the code where I'm facing an exception all the time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

from .ava_dataset import Ava  # noqa
from .build import DATASET_REGISTRY, build_dataset  # noqa
from .charades import Charades  # noqa
from .imagenet import Imagenet  # noqa
from .kinetics import Kinetics  # noqa
from .ssv2 import Ssv2  # noqa
from .epickitchens import Epickitchens  # noqa


try:
    from .ptv_datasets import Ptvcharades, Ptvkinetics, Ptvssv2  # noqa
except Exception:
    print("Please update your PyTorchVideo to latest master")
```

I'm getting the `Please update your PyTorchVideo to latest master` exception in every run. How can I fix this? I have done

> pip install pytorchvideo

and it's correcly installed, I also tried to install it from github repo. If someone has any idea would be really useful.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What is your pytorchvideo version ? the latest should be 0.1.5.
If it is not then:
`pip install --upgrade pytorchvideo`